# Unable to run my django&bootstrap site with Let's Encrypt on DO Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt

I am trying to launch a django website and I want to install and make sure https connection works with let's encrypt for my site.

I followed DigitalOcean "How To Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 18.04" tutorial on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04. When my site works with http connection, after the installation of let's encrypt, neither http nor https connection works now.

My nginx/sites-available/mysite.com file code is shown below:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/project/app/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Normally, my website with http works fine, yet when I follow the tutorial and try to connect my site, it does not load on browser. If I try with curl, I get response: curl: (7) Failed to connect to mysite.com port 443: Connection refused.

Comment: Anything in your nginx logs when you (re-)start nginx server?

Comment: No issue on nginx restart @Oliver

Comment: Can you add the output of `netstat -nltp | grep nginx`? Is anything listening on port 443?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by applying everything through a new user with sudo privileges. Then, all issues are solved and https connection works well.

Thanks everyone for the support and help.